# How do I add a module to the text of a basic page in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7

How do I add a module to the text of a basic page in drupal 7 ?

I need some help.  I am having some problems with the drupal donations module

I have done this before on this web site
http://www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26/content/donate-using-paypal

But now I can;t remember how I did this.

How do I put this module on a page I am creating?  When I go to create the page, there does not seem to be an option to past complex tables or controls on it.  I just has a large empty text area to edit the body of the text

I thnhk this is a simple thing.

I was able to find the setting for
    Home >> Adminstration >> Configuration >> Web Services == PalPal donation
and that set up the control

So I know it is ready to plop into the page

How do I plop it into the page?  I remember there was something like a button bar associated with the text editor for the page that allowed me to add complex items like tables and like this particular module.

Comment: Use node preprocess or some hook_page ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be read in that module's Documentation, the module creates two blocks.

The steps you need to follow:

1. Create an empty node of any content type. You can alter the URL and attach it to a menu item as well.
2. Go to **admin/structure/block** and find the blocks your module provides.
3. Hit "configure" on one or both of them.
4. In each block's settings, in the "pages" section (bottom of your screen) select "Only the listed pages" and enter the url of the empty page you created before.